# MySQL command line not doing anything

Tags: mysql, command-line

I'm completely new to SQL and am following the MySQL tutorial for set up. In the command line client, none of the commands seem to do anything except give me an arrow `->`  which just sits there. I've tried the `SHOW DATABASES` and `CREATE DATABASE test` commands and nothing. The only thing that seems to do anything is the `\c` command which removes the arrow and takes me back to the `mysql>` prompt. This is an example of what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Ah, I remember those days. The simple mistakes you make when just starting out. Glad you got an answer already. Please be sure to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to terminate the command with a semicolon (`;`).

Comment: Or you terminate it with a literal `\G` to show 'vertical table' output instead of 'horizontal table' output.